# Running Asterisk on Windows Server 2008 R2 as a virtual machine?

Tags: asterisk

I am configuring a site for a Service Center and i have an HP Proliant server with a dual Xeon  CPUs. I want to know if its a good idea to run the Asterisk platform as a virtual machine on Windows Server 2008 R2. 
Up to 15 agents will be active concurrently and beside that i will probably need to activate Recording of calls, generating reports etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can run asterisk in vmware or virtualbox. Running in hyper-v never sucess for me. Vmware have more chance to work ok.

But under hi load(more then 10 call) you can experience sound quality issues.

So it is not recomended run in production with 15 concurrent calls.

Comment: only if you able forward that card. USB card will work for sure, pci card - no idea how to forward it to vm.

Answer (score 0):

Since voice is likely the single most demanding network traffic stream that most of us sysadmin will ever come across, you need to be way, way, way, out ahead of this one. Unless you are prepared to dedicate many years, non-stop, of your life to debugging and programming and mastering the tiniest nuances of timing sources inside of guests, using various hypervisors, with various hypervisor configurations, at 1000 clock ticks per second as that relates to which CODEC you are using, baed on whether or not you are going to have 1 call or 10 calls or 100 calls going, and whether or not you will be recording those calls, and whether or not any one else on the system will be having a conference call at the same time, based on the exact version of the daemon and the driver, then, I would humbly and professionally recommend going another route now, and saving  your head and your hair for some thing actually worth your time.

Comment: Thanks, i already have my Asterisk+Elastix on a dedicated server just because of things you mentioned.

Comment: There are nothing so special. Currently it have no so many issues with virtualization.